# object attributes not changing when method called

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pygame

I've got an object that I've created, it has an attribute `color` which is a tuple `(0, 0, 0)`. I've written some methods that *should* randomly reset one (and only one) of these RGB values to 0, but despite the methods getting called the value of `color` stays the same. here is the class definition :

```py
class block:
    def __init__(self , pos , inc , size):
        self.posX , self.posY = pos
        self.posX *= blocks
        self.posY *= blocks
        self.sizeX , self.sizeY = size
        self.sizeX *= blocks
        self.sizeY *= blocks
        self.color = (255 , 255 , 255)
        self.incrementer = inc

    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.rect(surface , self.color , (self.posX , self.posY , self.posX + self.sizeX , self.posY + self.sizeY))
        pg.display.update()
        self.updateCol(self.incrementer)

    def setR(self):
        R , G , B = self.color
        self.color = (0 , G , B)

    def setG(self):
        R , G , B = self.color
        self.color = (R , 0 , B)

    def setB(self):
        R , G , B = self.color
        self.color = (R , G , 0)

    def call_set_color(self, set_func, color):
        if color >= 255 - (self.incrementer + 1):
            set_func()
        else:
            return color

    def reduceRGB(self):
        R , G , B = self.color
        color, func = r.choice([(R , self.setR),(G , self.setG),(B , self.setB)])
        self.call_set_color(func, color)
        
        
    def updateCol(self , inc):
        R , G , B = self.color
        if R < 255 and G < 255 and B < 255 and not ((R + inc or G + inc or B + inc) > 255):
            self.color = (R + inc , G + inc , B + inc)
        else:
            self.reduceRGB()
```

outside of the definition, the method `draw` gets called

i instantiate the object useing:

```py
block((X , Y) , 10 , (screenX // blocks , screenY // blocks))
```

Comment: Can you show your object instantiation?

Comment: call_set_color is called in the reduceRGB function on the last line, I will add my object instantiation code

Comment: This line `if color >= 255 - (self.incrementer + 1):` will always initially be false. I'll add an answer as to why.

Answer (score 0):

A few things..

You initialize the color as `(255, 255, 255)`.

I believe you do this with the expectation it will force it to randomly set one to zero.

When you call your `updateCol` method, this condition `if R < 255 and G < 255 and B < 255 ..` being `False` forces your program to execute your else clause.

```
self.reduceRGB()
```

In `self.reduceRGB` you use `r.choice` which I assume is `random.choice` to randomly select a color and it's corresponding color.

```
color, func = r.choice([(R , self.setR),(G , self.setG),(B , self.setB)])
self.call_set_color(func, color)
```

But within `call_set_color` just returns the same `color`.
`color` which is still it's initial value of `255` You compare to `255` minus `(self.incrementer + 1)`(`9`) equals `246`.
So basically you are saying,
If 255 is less or equal then 246, run the function.
Since this is always `False`, it will never run your function.

Additionally, this line

```
if R < 255 and G < 255 and B < 255 and not ((R + inc or G + inc or B + inc) > 255)
```

probably doesn't do what you think it does.
This part specifically `not ((R + inc or G + inc or B + inc) > 255)` does not check each individual sum and compare them to `255`. It takes the first one that is not equal to `0` and compares it to `255`.

Comment: ok, ive changed that to : `if R < 255 and G < 255 and B < 255 and not (R + inc > 255 or G + inc > 255 or B + inc> 255):`

Comment: I believe what you meant is to check to make sure it didn't randomly pick one that could still be incremented. If this is the case, `if color + self.incrementer > 255:` would suffice.